# How can I find a broken disc?

Tags: mdadm, raid6

I have a problem. I got 1 broken disc in RAID6. How can I find which one broke down?

I've tried

```
# cat /proc/mdstat  <--- to check condition of raid.
```

I want to know if this command

```
mdadm –detail /dev/md0
```

will give me the serial number of the physical disc.

Comment: with `mdadm –detail /dev/md0` you will get disk details post that you can use so many utilities to find serial number like `smartctl` and many more. Have tried those?